# Python to execute user input grep commands securely

Tags: python, python-3.x, grep, subprocess

How do I execute linux grep using python? My current attempt is the following

```
    output = subprocess.run(
        "/bin/grep " + query,
        cwd=path_to_files,
        stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr = subprocess.PIPE,
        shell=True
    )
```

Which works. Issue however is that query can include untrusted commands (eg. if they append a semicolon in the query, they can possibly run a second command in addition to the initial grep). How could I securely accept user inputs to the grep command?

Comment: The best way is not trust user input to be safe at all. Especially with `shell=True`. You need to restrict the query as much as possible. And that will depend on your use-case

Comment: I understand that `shell=True` is what makes this query dangerous. If I remove shell=True, subprocess would not execute by throwing a `FileNotFoundError` error. I would like to give my users access to use grep on a single folder, recursively.

Comment: Remove `shell=True`. Use `chroot` jail. Maybe symlink the `grep` binary to the local directory to get around the `FileNotFoundError`

Comment: Where is the list of filenames to grep? Is that part of `query`?

Comment: Correct. The user would, for example, enter `-r "pokedex" */*.html` into the input. Which translate to the `query` variable.

Comment: Oh that sucks, since you need `shell=True` to expand wildcards.

Comment: Would it be possible to remove the `shell=True` if I, say, have a list of files to grep on? `allowed_files = ["file1.txt", "file2.txt", "nested/file3.txt"]` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Insead of use `shell=True`, you can send a list to `subprocess.run`.

```
import shlex

output = subprocess.run(
    ["/bin/grep "] + shlex.split(query),
    cwd=path_to_files,
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr = subprocess.PIPE
)
```

This code prevent using `;` for shell injection.

Another problem is that the user can access all files in the system.
You can use `chroot` for prevent a user to go above that the given file or you can modify your code for to be able to check which file the user will open.